# Interpreting `man` C library name

Tags: c, man

Certain C library files show multiple `#include` files at the top.  For instance, `man connect` shows

```
SYNOPSIS
  #include <sys/types.h>
  #include <sys/socket.h>
```

However, in order to call the `connect` command, only including `sys/socket.h` is necessary.  Why do they arrange source code so that including another file is also necessary?  Are there cases where you wish to avoid including `sys/types.h`?

Comment: What Unix is this? My OpenBSD system's `connect(2)` manual only mentions `sys/socket.h`.

Comment: It's Mac BSD...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/connect) Notes section:

> POSIX.1-2001 does not require the inclusion of `<sys/types.h>`, and this header file is not required on Linux. However, some historical (BSD) implementations required this header file, and portable applications are probably wise to include it.

I guess that is why the Mac man page includes `sys/types.h` as well.

Comment: I guess I should have typed the same command on a Linux VM, to see the answer to my question.  Oops.